# Convert MySQL to SQLite using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

i want to convert mysql database to sqlite database, is there a way to do this using php or some other tool? i have downloaded a firefox addon and there is also an option to import sql, but this does not work for me.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489277/script-to-convert-mysql-dump-sql-file-into-format-that-can-be-imported-into-sqlit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the tools [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools).

Comment: there are paid tools, and free are not using php.

Comment: try [this](https://gist.github.com/943776) from the list.
Also some of the tools may have a trial version which you could use.

Comment: thanks Jan for your quick response, but still this is not in php

Comment: [This is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060029/how-to-convert-mysql-to-sqlite3-using-php) This should help. There's no super easy way though.